# GWT TabPanel CSS style with image

Tags: gwt

I have some panel in my project and I can't change the default style of it (light Blue) - I want image in the tab. I follow several tutorials but can't find it out.

Please help me out how to do it?

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();

Panel controlPanel = new Panel("Discovery");

tabPanel.add(controlPanel);
```

... and I have both my project css and custom css.

Where we change css so modify our tab panel?

Comment: It would be better to show that how you changed

Answer (score 0):

[addStyleName](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleName%28java.lang.String%29)  and  [setStyleName](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setStyleName%28java.lang.String%29)  are the methods you are probably looking for. You can find more general information about CSS styling in GWT [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Panel controlPanel = new Panel("Discovery");
```

The above line is really scary in `GWT`.You cannot instantiate the [Panel Class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html) like that because the Panel class in `Abstract`

And coming to default styles

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
tabPanel.setStylePrimaryName("yourStyle");
```

The `setStylePrimaryName`  ovverides the default `styles`.

If you want to add some extra css classes to existing default style  use

```
 tabPanel.addStyleName("myExtraStyles");
```